# Drive recovery – `ddrescue` hanging

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I'm using `ddrescue` to recover files from a hard drive. Details:

- 500GB SATA drive,
- 2 Partitions (e.g. `sdb2`, `sdb3`) – each with about 200 GB of data,
- connected with SATA adapter to USB,
- running: `sudo ddrescue -d /dev/sdb2 sdb2.img sdb2.logfile --force -R`.

The disk is pretty damaged from what I've experienced:

- Takes a very long time to mount and browse.
- Becomes unresponsive intermittently.
- Not much luck copying across files individually one by one.

I've been running `ddrescue` on each partition and see something strange but which gives me hope.

- `ddrescue` just seems to hang at various points in time, i.e. `ipos` and `opos` don't move and neither does `run time`. Current rate stays very high and does not change. What is happening here? Is the drive just becoming completely unresponsive for a while?
- Very often `ddrescue` is not making any progress rescuing anything and `last sucessful read` starts to count up for a very long time – indefinitely really. When this happens I `^C` out, powercycle the drive and start `ddrescue` again. Surprisingly it immediately starts succeeding in rescuing files at very high speeds. Sometimes this lasts and sometimes it's dead in the water after a few seconds.

It looks like this:

```
rescued:    10970 MB,  errsize:    338 MB,  current rate:   15073 kB/s
   ipos:   191426 MB,   errors:    3806,    average rate:   15612 kB/s
   opos:   191426 MB, run time:    1.65 m,  successful read:       0 s ago
```

and a while later:

```
rescued:    11402 MB,  errsize:    600 MB,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:   144382 MB,   errors:    7149,    average rate:    4299 kB/s
   opos:   144382 MB, run time:    7.66 m,  successful read:    2.06 m ago
```

The fact that the drive reads absolutely fine for a while after it's first plugged in makes me think there is something other than bad sectors at play here. Could I for example write a bash script that power cycles and restarts `ddrescue` often? Will this kill the drive? For info, I took some practices into play from [this post about `ddrescue`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79225/is-this-ddrescue-command-doing-anything?newreg=37c69954f0f14daa8d612f8850e5ce70).

Answer (score 5):

SATA to USB adapters vary.  Some of them forget about the disk upon encountering I/O errors while others return I/O errors and continue.  There is a wide range of behaviors depending on which adapter you're using.

I think that yours is blocking all I/O until it is power cycled.

You probably can't physically disconnect and reconnect the adapter from the command line to reset its power status, but you can try to [reset the USB device or USB ports](https://askubuntu.com/q/645/18979).

If that doesn't work, I recommend plugging in the hard drive directly by SATA and then running `ddrescue` while the hard drive is plugged in by SATA.  That way, you would bypass the USB adapter, which seems to get stuck upon each error.

Comment: Thanks, yea resetting USB port was what I was thinking for power cycle. I'm quite convinced that it could be the adapter. I will try direct sata when i get my hands on a PC